# I tried to apply patch 10266 at my Magento version 1.9.0.1. How to test it that is it applied or not?

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

I tried to apply patch 10266 at my `Magento version 1.9.0.1`. How to test it that is it applied or not?

And one strange thing is that applied.patches.list file in app/etc/ does not exist.

`Magereport.com` also not showing the status of patch 10266.
Then how will I confirm that patch installed or not? I run the script by PHP file.

> echo shell_exec("sh
>   PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.9.0.1_v1-2017-09-13-06-31-01.sh") or die("bash
>   didn't work");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your `.sh file` and check the changes.

You downloaded from here: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

Example : This code was in  "PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.9.3.4_v1-2017-09-13-06-39-58.sh" and you can see that the patch insert some lines with + or delete with -

```
diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
index 1c4c515..b378fe6 100644
--- app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
@@ -51,6 +51,13 @@ class Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Actio
     protected $_publicActions = array();

     /**
+     *Array of actions which can't be processed without form key validation
+     *
+     * @var array
+     */
+    protected $_forcedFormKeyActions = array();
+
+    /**
      * Used module name in current adminhtml controller
      */
     protected $_usedModuleName = 'adminhtml';
@@ -162,7 +169,7 @@ class Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Actio
         $_isValidSecretKey = true;
         $_keyErrorMsg = '';
         if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
-            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
+            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() || $this->_checkIsForcedFormKeyAction()) {
                 $_isValidFormKey = $this->_validateFormKey();
                 $_keyErrorMsg = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.');
             } elseif (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->useSecretKey()) {
@@ -179,6 +186,9 @@ class Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Actio
                     'message' => $_keyErrorMsg
                 )));
             } else {
+                if ($_keyErrorMsg != ''){
+                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($_keyErrorMsg);
+                }
                 $this->_redirect( Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getStartupPageUrl() );
             }
             return $this;
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but no luck